# my tic-tac-toe game if condition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, tic-tac-toe

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

let turn = "x";

cells.forEach( box => {
    box.addEventListener("click",
     () => box.classList.add("fill-" + turn));   

     if ( turn === "x" ) turn = "o";
     else turn = "x";
     
},
 { once: true}
);
```

```css
#board{
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: auto;
  
  
}

.cell{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(241, 239, 239);
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.cell:hover{
  background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);

}

.cell.fill-x::after{
  content: "x";
  color: blue;
}

.cell.fill-o::after{
  content: "0";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Dooz</title>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dooz.css">
 
 </head>
 <body>
  
   <div id="board">
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
    <a  class="cell"></a>
   </div>

   <script src="dooz.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm learning javascript and trying to build a tic-tac-toe game.
I want to create an if condition to whether choose "x" or "o" after another, but my code doesn't work probably.
inside second if statement line:
when it's ( turn = "o" ), it only shows "o"
when it's (turn === or == "o"), it only shows "x"
What's the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: "doesn't work probably" -- what does this mean?  What do you mean by "shows"?

Comment: What is `box`? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: You've erased my indentation correction, but the indentation correction helps explain what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using arrow function as second parameter in click event listener. Arrow functions can only run one statement if you don't specify a body using curly brackets.

```
let cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

let turn = "x";

cells.forEach( box => {
    box.addEventListener("click",
     () => {
       box.classList.add("fill-" + turn));   

       if ( turn === "x" ) turn = "o";
       else turn = "x";
     });
},
 { once: true}
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I changed it to normal function but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @mh.nasri you should also put your if-else conditions inside the even listener function's body. That's the logic.

Comment: thanks, it works now! I didn't notice the brackets! gonna delete this stupid mistake from here.

Comment: @mh.nasri you are welcome. Also, you don't need to use normal function declaration to wrap lines of statements in a body. You could use your arrow function with a body wrapping up your statements inside a pair of curly brackets. I mean they are the same, except arrow functions don't have refence to the function itself with `this` keyword. Another tip, you could listen for click event on your cell container (game container) and then decide which cell is being actually clicked using event handler's `event` object instead of listening for click event on each cell, it's not the preferred way.